# Enforce same collation on multiple SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server, collation

Multiple SQL Server databases with the exact same schema somehow ended up having different collations. How do I change them all to be the same with a scripted approach without any manual clicking around?

```
declare @rename_models table (
    wrong nvarchar(256) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, -- tried overriding collation, but this conflicts with some of the databases
    correct nvarchar(256) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
);
```

The query I run against a `models` table:

```
select code as to_be_deleted from models where code in (select wrong from @rename_models);
```

Throws this for some databases:

```
MESSAGE
"Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 140
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between ""SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"" and ""Latin1_General_CI_AS"" in the equal to operation.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the COLLATE keyword in your Select Query.

> Casting the collation of an expression.
>
> You can use the COLLATE clause to apply a character expression to a
>   certain collation. Character literals and variables are assigned the
>   default collation of the current database. Column references are
>   assigned the definition collation of the column.

References :
[COLLATE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Note my comment in the first bit of SQL. When I override the collation, it conflicts with the other databases. I'm asking how to fix the collation in all my databases.

Comment: Not all collations are compatible